# Parameters based on case object

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I'm moving from a very hard coded Java implementation to a very modular Scala implementation and I've gotten stuck translating a part of my application.

The function I'm looking at produces a message from a format string. It looks up the relevant information in a database and uses it to format the string.

```
public static String getHumanizedMessage(Type type, User user, Long relatedId){
    switch(type.getTypeName()){
    case NEW_FOO:{
        Foo foo = Foo.findById(relatedId);
        return String.format(type.getMessage(), user.name, foo.name);
    }
    case BAR_SHARED:{
        Bar bar = Bar.findById(relatedId);
        Baz baz = Baz.findById(relatedId);
        return String.format(type.getMessage(), user.name, bar.name, baz.name);
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

So, on the Scala side of things, I've tried to implement the different types using case objects which all extend from a base `Type`.

```
sealed class Type(val name: String)

case object NewFoo extends Type("New Foo")
case object BarShared extends Type("Bar Shared")
```

Problem is, with my application being modular, in my `MessageService` I don't have access `Foo.findById`, `Bar.findById` or `Baz.findById`. What I would like it to receive the appropriate strings in the parameter list, but as you can see, the number of parameters varies based on the `Type`. I could make the parameters optional, but then anyone calling the function needs to know which parameters are necessary based on the type, and I don't like that. I suppose I could have a different function name for each type, but I'd rather not, if there's a better way.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really follow your last paragraph. Could you rephrase/clarify what exactly you want to do? What is this `MessageService`? Where would you like to receive appropriate strings?

Comment: I'm breaking the project into modules where the modules have services to provide functionality. This is all happening in my `MessageService`, which doesn't have access to `UserService` or `BarService` in order to call database methods like `findById`. So my `getHumanizedMessage` can't just take `relatedId` as a parameter and find the object it needs. I want to take `String` parameters. But the number of strings I need won't always be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to encode the knowledge of formatting a `Type` in that type. If your aim is to keep the `MessageService` agnostic to whatever data may come in, you could e.g. require each type to format itself, such as:

```
trait MessageType {
  val name: String
  def format(relatedId: Long): String
}

case class FooMessageType(foo: Foo) extends MessageType {
  val name = "Foo"
  def format(relatedIid: Long) = {
    val foo = Foo.findById(relatedId)
    "This is ${foo.name}"
  }
}
```

Then your `MessageService` would only know about the `MessageType` interface, and implementations thereof would be provided in different modules. Note that you likely would need to allow each module to register its MessageTypes against the MessageService at startup.

Answer (score 1):

It seems weird to me that this `getHumanizedMessage()` was one single method to begin with. Because of your switch statement, you do two completely different things in one function. Why don't you split them up?

You can write:

```
def getHumanizedMessage(foo: Foo, user: User) = String.format(NewFoo.getMessage(), user.name, foo.name)
def getHumanizedMessage(bar: Bar, baz: Baz, user: User) = String.format(BarShared.getMessage(), bar.name, baz.name, user.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a `sealed` implementation for an easy match statement, you just need to have an abstract class as the base.

```
sealed abstract class MessageType {
  val name: String
  def findById[A](relatedId: Long): A
}
```

You can then extend case objects or case classes depending on your use cases:

```
case object NewFoo extends MessageType {
  val name: String = "NewFoo"
  def findById(relatedId: Long): NewFoo = {...}
}
```

or if you want to provide arguments:

```
case class BarShared(defaultName: String) extends MessageType {
  val name: String = defaultName
  def findById(relatedId: Long) BarShared = {...}
}
```

With the sealed class your match statement doesn't need a default, unless you define it as an extension.